# Get the password after encoded by PasswordEncoder and generated with jwt in spring boot security

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I'm working with **Spring Boot Security**.

I have to **Sign up** a user (`name`, `login`, `password`, ... .),
the `password` inserted to oracle DB is encoded using **`PasswordEncoder`**.

Then the **Sign in** is implemented with **`JWT`**.

I'd like to recuperate the `password` registered in DB, but it's not possible with **`PasswordEncoder`**.
That's why I used **`StandardPBEStringEncryptor`** which allowed decrypt the encrypted registered `password`.
But, now, I faced another problem which is :

> encoded password does not look like bcrypt jwt

Could you please tell me if I missed something ? Have you any idea to recuperate the registered password ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Passwords should not be stored in a way that they can be recuperated. That's not safe. If someone forgot the password they should create a new one.

Comment: thanks Sir @JPS for your reply, so `jwt` can only implemented with `PasswordEncoder`.big thanks again.

Comment: storing password in any shape way or form that can be decrypted is a massive security risk and should NEVER be implemented.